# Set iOS app version numbers to an integer representing the current date-time in UTC

Tags: ios, xcode, version-numbering

I want both the version numbers (`CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString`) in Xcode 5 to be automatically set to the current date-time in [UTC time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) every time I do a build.

For example, `201405041942` means `May 4, 2014 at 7:42 PM UTC`.

Answer (score 10):

## Automate Setting Version Numbers

You can tell Xcode 5 on [Mountain Lion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) or [Mavericks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) to execute a tiny [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) (Unix) script on each build to automatically set your two version numbers.

In the Xcode project > Build Phases > Run Script

(1) Set "Shell" to:

```
/bin/sh
```

(2) Set the bash script field to:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(date -u "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

For the checkboxes, mine are set to…

• Check the box "Show environment variables in build log

• Uncheck the box "Run script only when installing".

[image: screen shot of Xcode project > Build Phases > Run Script]

After a build, you can verify the version numbers in Xcode project > General > Identity.

[image: screen shot of Xcode project > General > Identity]

## Third Version Number

Be aware that your app's record on Apple's [iTunesConnect web site](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) defines a version number. If that number fails to match either `CFBundleVersion` or `CFBundleShortVersionString` you will get a warning. That warning may be ignored as it is not a show-stopping error.